# Why I receive: 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have this Dockerfile I use to deploy my nodejs app together with nginx:

```
    #Create our image from Node
FROM node:latest as builder

MAINTAINER Cristi Boariu <cristiboariu@gmail.com>

# use changes to package.json to force Docker not to use the cache
# when we change our application's nodejs dependencies:
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /opt/app/

# From here we load our application's code in, therefore the previous docker
# "layer" thats been cached will be used if possible
WORKDIR /opt/app
ADD . /opt/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD npm start

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY nginx/star_zuumapp_com.chained.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY nginx/star_zuumapp_com.key /etc/nginx/ssl/

RUN  cd /etc/nginx && chmod -R 600 ssl/

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and this is my nginx file:

```
    upstream api-server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev.error.log debug;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://api-server;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/star_example_com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star_example_com.key;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://api-server;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I already spent a few hours debugging this without success.

Basically, I receive:

> 502 Bad Gateway

when trying to test it locally on:

```
https://localhost/docs/#
```

From docker logs:

```
    172.17.0.1 - - [04/May/2018:05:35:36 +0000] "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
2018/05/04 05:35:36 [error] 7#7: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/docs/", host: "localhost"
```

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Have you tried with the right IP instead of "localhost"?

Comment: @Dalton Yes, I also tried with my site after deploying it to kubernetes: https://example.com/docs/# and the same error appears.

Comment: How about the right port used?

Comment: Try updating host systems's (localhost) host file (/etc/hosts in Linux or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts for windows) and add an extra alias  www.example.com   for 127.0.0.1 and then browse your application using www.example.com in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure:

```
server 172.17.42.1:8080;
```

`172.17.42.1` is gateway ip address of docker.

or

```
server app_ipaddress_container:8080;
```

in nginx.conf file.

Because of port 8080 is listened on host, not on the container.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that default port now is: https://github.com/zbwright/docs/commit/63c075701d3865ca54af7a608dfbc34304217008 (`172.17.0.1`) so I put this but stil received: `connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.1:8080/docs/", host: "localhost"`. Maybe I should have a single nginx container and start node inside nginx image?

Comment: put ip address of nodejs container, find out it using `docker inspect nodejsdockercontainer`

Comment: Yes if I comment out nginx docker container and let only the first image (nodejs) I can successfully open: `http://localhost:8080/docs` in the browser.

Comment: oh, just check again, you build nginx and nodejsapp in 1 container only ?

Comment: Yeah... I cannot use docker compose. So I think now to copy nodejs files to nginx image and start npm there...

Comment: check that https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ for multi services in 1 container